# UWP + Cordova App + Testing on XBox One

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-cordova, xbox-one

I am trying to test my game on the XBox One after having successfully built a project that works fine on Local Machine, x64, with Visual Studio 2017. Latest versions of everything. It's a Cordova type project.

Now I have it on there, and uploaded using the XBox Device Portal thing. When I play it (a RPG Maker MV game), there's no sound, even though testing locally using my Visual Studio the sound works fine. Isn't the system Edge browser-based, just like the system in Visual Studio?

I've tried using the Cordova Media plugin, no luck, and tried using .MP3 instead of .OGG, still no luck. The default Media Player in RPG Maker MV doesn't work at all.

For Windows 10/VS, I ended up replacing the audio system using Howler.js, and that worked for Win10, but not XBox One.

Does anyone have suggestions I could try? At this point, i'd even be willing to pay someone to help me with this issue.

Comment: Could you please post related codes or share a basic minimal demo to show what you have tried?

Comment: UWP on Xbox One can't run x86, only x64. You need to provide more details here for sure.

Comment: I added more details to the original post about my setup and what i've tried.

Comment: Did you get any error from cordova media plugin? Or no error, just no sound?

Comment: No error messages that I can find, just no sound at all.

Comment: I've created an blank cordova project with `cordova-media-plugin` and played an mp3 file on xbox one.  The music was played correctly.  Could you please try other .mp3 files? if the problem still persists, there must be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: Elvis: Did you set it up the way I did above? Can paths cause sounds not to play? What are examples of issues that can cause it to work fine on Local Machine/Windows 10, but not XBox?

Comment: Update: Smaller sounds, like sound effects, work fine on XBox, but larger music .OGG sounds do not work. Is there a file size limit for Cordova Media Player?

Comment: Except for machine's defects or unsupported API, I can't think of issues that can cause it  to work fine on local Machine/Windows 10 but not XBox. But from the [source codes of cordova-media-plugin line 34](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/windows/MediaProxy.js#L34), `.OGG` is not even supported.

Comment: Just downloaded an `.ogg` music and tried playing it with my demo on windows 10/VS. There is no sound at all.